# Python - Oracle 11g connection

Tags: python

I want to connect python and oracle 11g.
Python Version- 3.6.1 / 64 bit, Windows 7 -64 bit.

I have installed cx_Oracle from https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/
The Code is as below -

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('sde/sde@orcl')
print (con.version)
con.close()
```

But I am getting below Error -

```
C:\Python\Python36\python.exe 
D:/Automation/Python_WP/practice/database/db_connection.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Automation/Python_WP/practice/database/db_connection.py", line 1, in <module>
import cx_Oracle
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please let me know the steps to connect Python 3.6.1 and Oracle 11g for Windows-7 64 bit.

Comment: did you installed it with pip or downloaded it?

Comment: I have installed cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.6-2.exe (md5).

Comment: use pip install cx_Oracle and try. hope it will resolve this error

Comment: C:\Python\Python36>pip install cx_Oracle
Requirement already satisfied: cx_Oracle in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages

Comment: I have also download the Oracle instant Client. << nstantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip >> and unzip it. Set this path to Environment Variable . ORACLE_HOME:C:\instantclient\instantclient Then install cx_Oracle <> But Still its not working.

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Facing above error.

Comment: download  msvcr100.dll file and paste it into <oracle_instant_client_dir>

Comment: by d way your python is 32 bit or 64bit? if your python and windows bit are not same then cx_python wont work.

Comment: Yes both are 64 bit. Okay I will try the dll file

Comment: NO, Still I am facing same problem.
I would request you, Could you please explain the all steps step by step like 1>.. 2>.. ... N>...
It would be very much helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Download msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll from the web.
2. Save them to your C:\Windows\System32 folder.
3. Save them to your C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder as well (if you have a 64-bit operating system).
```

Now try running your code file in Python and it will load the graph in couple of seconds.

Comment: In my system Windows 7, Python 3.6.1 and Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 are 64 bit.
I have the following -
    1. Download msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll from the web.
    2. Save them to your C:\Windows\System32 folder.
    3. Save them to your C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder as well
    4. Download instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.3.0.zip and set up this path in Environment variable -> System Variable -> path. Also in the same directory i have paste msvcr100.dll file
    5. Download and install cx_Oracle-5.3-11g.win-amd64-py3.6-2.exe
But still import cx_Oracle is showing error.